# Are faster high-capacity microSD cards less compatible?

Tags: compatibility, memory-card, micro-sd-card

I have heard claims that **faster** high-capacity (64GB+) microSD cards will not work in some devices in which **slower** cards will work.

I have not been able to correlate this to any particular brands or models.  It seems to be more prevalent in devices that are only guaranteed to work with cards up to 32GB (SDHC), but still work with larger cards (SDXC).

Is there any reason why this would be true?  Or is it an urban legend in the making?

Answer (score 1):

I know putting a microSD card higher than 32GB into a Nintendo 3DS only works if it is formatted to FAT32, and so Nintendo just says the cap is 32GB to avoid confusion.

"Nintendo cannot add support for SDXC cards because they come formatted with with exFAT, a Microsoft proprietary file system for which Microsoft holds a patent.  When the patent expires, Nintendo could add support for SDXC cards formatted with exFAT.

Until then, like you said, if you buy an SDXC card and format it with the FAT32 filesystem, it should work on the 3DS.  In theory, the capacity supported could be as high as 2TB (the upper limit of the SDXC standard as well as FAT32)."

Don't know about any other devices, though I would imagine the reason is similar.

Source: http://techforums.nintendo.com/thread/16696

Comment: You probably misread the question.  It's about the effect of speed rather than size.

Comment: @fixer1234 I agree, but the info is so good and useful I didn't want to mention it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, No, newer cards are not less compatible. You may find a few pieces of older equipment that have an issue with the speed of the newer cards, but I think that would be more the exception than the rule. That being said, there are several other factors that would need to be considered using newer cards in older devices including capacity, format, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any idea why a few pieces of older equipment may have an issue with the speed of the newer cards?

Comment: Most likely because they don't understand the capability of the card, so they either refuse to work, or work the slowest possible speeds because it doesn't understand what the card is capable of.